# load bmp image from byte array in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, bmp

I am new to android,I developed one sample application which load the image from sd card and display as a bitmap image using image view controll.
Now i want to modify my  application like  load the bmp from byte array i have the raw image ,width and height ,do any one have sample for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below Code for Convert Byte Array to Bitmap and display this bitmap into ImageView.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

and see below SO link for more information.

[Convert ByteArray to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity/11519855#11519855)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `BitmapFactory`.

```
public static Bitmap decodeByteArray (byte[] data, int offset, int length)
```

For more info, [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in Drawable folder try this code

```
    Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);

    //Type cast to BitmapDrawable
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

    //Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified outputstream via compress method.    
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    byte[] buffer  = stream.toByteArray();
```