# How to set image in second Activity from first Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to set image in second Activity from first Activity?Please I have a serious Problem with it.Help me for this.

Edit (this has been copied from the comment):

First Activity code for Intent put Extra:

```
in.putExtra("image", marraylist_image.get(arg2).toString());
```

Second Activity code for Set image in imageview

```
image = mbundle.getString("image"); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image); 
System.out.println("Image Value:--" + bmp); 
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: First Activity code for Intent put Extra:in.putExtra("image", marraylist_image.get(arg2).toString()); Second Activity code for Set image in imageview image = mbundle.getString("image");
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
  System.out.println("Image Value:--" + bmp);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: How you declare marraylist_image?

Comment: check here may it is your solution 

[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles/7890405#7890405)

Comment: check here may it is your solution

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles/7890405#7890405

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles/7890405#7890405

Answer (score 0):

**Activity1:**

```
bytes[] imgs = ... // your image
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("img", imgs);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2:**

```
bytes[] receiver = getIntent().getExtra("img");
```

Also refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519855/1405983) answer.

Comment: hey please read my first comment.here i used Arralist to add image to listview.I want to display that image in Second Activity in Imageview.]

Comment: First convert your bitmap to bytes[] then pass it to next activity after that at second activity catch all bytes[] and again convert it to bitmap and display it into your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Using bundle you can pass your image to seconfd activity like this :

```
               intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("imageurl", "your image string");
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

and in second activity:

```
 bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                   imageurl_of_event = bundle.getString("imageurl");
```

and for displaying image:

```
HttpURLConnection conn;
                try {
                    URL feedImage = new URL(imageurl_of_event);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) feedImage.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    event_imageview.setImageBitmap(img);
}catch.....
```

thats it