# Get the image from other class with layout xml to the button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am searching for the coding for get the image from another java file with xml layout return back to a button. And then the button will show the image which I selected.
Anyone can help me about this? What I need is I want the button 'A' get the image from `IconGridView.class` ?

```
Button A = (Button) findViewById (R.id.a);
A.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
startActivity(new Intent(this, IconGridView.class));    

}
```

IconGridView.java

```
icon = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    icon.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(this));
```

IconAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// saving all images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.android,R.drawable.w7,
        R.drawable.blogger,R.drawable.google,R.drawable.fb,R.drawable.youtube,R.drawable.msn,R.drawable.gmail,R.drawable.twitter,
        R.drawable.chrome,R.drawable.firefox,R.drawable.instagram,
        R.drawable.emoji1,R.drawable.emoji2,R.drawable.emoji3,R.drawable.emoji4,
        R.drawable.emoji5,R.drawable.emoji6,R.drawable.emoji7,
        R.drawable.love,R.drawable.love1,R.drawable.love2,R.drawable.rose,
        R.drawable.punch,R.drawable.good,R.drawable.peace,
        R.drawable.beer,R.drawable.book,R.drawable.calendar,R.drawable.chat,
        R.drawable.clip,R.drawable.cone,R.drawable.contact,
        R.drawable.cpleset,R.drawable.cross,R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.laptop,R.drawable.lock,R.drawable.lock1,R.drawable.key,R.drawable.music,R.drawable.nosmoke,R.drawable.note,
        R.drawable.pills,R.drawable.printer,R.drawable.rain,R.drawable.sun,
        R.drawable.recycle,R.drawable.search,R.drawable.shopping,R.drawable.survey,
        R.drawable.sx,R.drawable.teacup,R.drawable.text,R.drawable.toilet,R.drawable.tree,
        R.drawable.up,R.drawable.down,R.drawable.check,R.drawable.qm,

};

// Constructor
public IconAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40, 40));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity. 1st solution in the answer is better one. Pass the image from one activity to another and use the same to set button background

Comment: are you extending ListActivity? Are you using a ListView?

Comment: @blackbelt, no. I am using gridView for the image on another xml layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your GridView instance you can set:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

the callback is triggered when you click on a element of your `GridView`. The position parameter refers to the element inside the adapter you clicked on:

So you can do:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           IconAdapter adapter = (IconAdapter) gridView.getAdapter() ;
           Integer drawableId = (Integer)yourAdapter.getItem(position);
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.putExtra("drawableId", drawabledId); 
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();   
        }
    });
```

you have to keep a reference to your IconAdapter, or you can try retrieving with:

```
IconAdapter adapter = (IconAdapter) gridView.getAdapter() ;
```

EDIT:
Use startActivityForResult in order to start `IconGridView`, and when the onItemClick of the gridview is called, finish IconGridView and set as extras for the result an intent with an extra parameter, the id of resource you want to use as background for your button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, IconGridView.class), 100);    

}



  @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode ==  Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         int drawableId = data.getIntExtra("drawableId", -1);
         if (drawableId != -1) {
             A.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Then where is the coding can set my Button 'A' with an image?

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood what you need. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I have a Button 'A', when I click the 'A' then it will comes out an iterface which is my IconGridView.java and there has an Adapter display the images with gridView, all the image display on that interface, and then I had click or choose the image from the interface, there will return the image which I had clicked in the Button A and the Button A will becum a button with the image.

Comment: so you want one of mThumbIds to be the background for your button?

Comment: yes I can . So when you click on a item of the gridview you want to came back to the previous activity and change button A background?

Comment: see my editi... See the  snippets of code in the WHOLE post. I made some modifications

Comment: What I confuse is `IconAdapter adapter = (IconAdapter) gridView.getAdapter() ;` where can put it? It is in my adapter class or GridView class? Another 1 error is the `REQUEST_CODE`, how can fix it? And then `(Integer)yourAdapter.getItem(position)` my `IconAdapter.getItem()` there dun has static, it is also error... so how can solve these?

Comment: alright... Thanks god... Lucky have you... Thank you very much what you advise me... ^^