# How to pass image from one activity to another

Tags: android

**Activity 1:**

```
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageicon);

in.putExtra("image",R.id.imageicon);
```

**Activity 2 :**

```
int RecipeImage = in.getIntExtra("image",0);

ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

imageview.setImageResource(RecipeImage);
```

**Issues :**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.wireframe/com.example.wireframe.singlemenuitem}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing image from one activity another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity)

Comment: It seems that something has not been initialized correctly in activity 2. Please provide the full stack trace and more code

Comment: your `in` is null in the secondActivity...Post your complete stack trace and also check whether intent extra is null or not before accessing it.

Comment: Also: image resources are `R.drawable`s, not `R.id` identifiers.

Comment: post more code, the complete stacktrace, and indicate at which line the issue occurs

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same image in two different activities, why not load the image for each activity? BTW you get the drawable in this way:

```
Drawable drawable =  this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage);
```