# Android how to insert image to a listview item from sqlite database and pass it into next activity

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, listview

I sucess to pass data from list view to next activity but now i need to add an image from my database to listview and then pass it to the next activity. Or if it's easeiest just pass the image to the next activity without show it in the listview.

```
package com.example.assfar.travel_guide;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.assfar.R;
import com.example.assfar.database.DBHelper;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TravelGuide extends ListActivity {

    private DBHelper dataBase;
    private List<String> guide_title_list= new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String,String> details= new HashMap<String,String>();
    private Cursor cursor;
    String title;
    Integer id;
    String desc;
    private ImageView imgv;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travelguide);

        imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        dataBase=  DBHelper.instance();
        SQLiteDatabase db= dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor= db.rawQuery("select * from Tour_Guide", null);

        if(cursor!=null) {
             if(cursor.moveToFirst());
             {
                do
                  {

         desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tour_Description"));
         title= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("guide_title")); 
         id= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
               guide_title_list.add("" + title +id );
                 details.put("" + title +id  ,title+desc+imgv);

                  } while(cursor.moveToNext());

             }

         }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, guide_title_list));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       //String selectedItem= ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

       String selectedValue= (String) getListAdapter(). getItem(position);
       String itemTitleDesc=(String) details.get(selectedValue);

       Intent i = new Intent(TravelGuide.this, Travel_Guide_Details.class);

        i.putExtra("selected item", selectedValue);
        i.putExtra("selected item", itemTitleDesc);
        startActivity(i);

        }
}
```

Comment: Check if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: no it dose't work because i need to pass image from database not from resources

Comment: you should use cache for store image from database and then get it in second activity.

Comment: How should i use cache?? i'm beginner in Android