# Android retrieve image from sqlite and pass it to next activity through listview item

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, listview

Thanks in advance. I sucess to pass data from list view to next activity but now i need to add an image from my database to listview and then pass it to the next activity. Or if it's easeiest just pass the image to the next activity without show it in the listview.

```
package com.example.assfar.travel_guide;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.assfar.R;
import com.example.assfar.database.DBHelper;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TravelGuide extends ListActivity {

    private DBHelper dataBase;
    private List<String> guide_title_list= new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String,String> details= new HashMap<String,String>();
    private Cursor cursor;
    String title;
    Integer id;
    String desc;
    private ImageView imgv;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travelguide);

        imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        dataBase=  DBHelper.instance();
        SQLiteDatabase db= dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor= db.rawQuery("select * from Tour_Guide", null);

        if(cursor!=null) {
             if(cursor.moveToFirst());
             {
                do
                  {

         desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tour_Description"));
         title= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("guide_title")); 
         id= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
               guide_title_list.add("" + title +id );
                 details.put("" + title +id  ,title+desc+imgv);

                  } while(cursor.moveToNext());

             }

         }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, guide_title_list));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       //String selectedItem= ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

       String selectedValue= (String) getListAdapter(). getItem(position);
       String itemTitleDesc=(String) details.get(selectedValue);

       Intent i = new Intent(TravelGuide.this, Travel_Guide_Details.class);

        i.putExtra("selected item", selectedValue);
        i.putExtra("selected item", itemTitleDesc);
        startActivity(i);

        }
}
```

next activity:

```
    package com.example.assfar.travel_guide;

import com.example.assfar.R;
import com.example.assfar.database.DBHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Travel_Guide_Details extends Activity {
    private DBHelper dataBase;


    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imgv;
    Bitmap bmp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_guide_details);

        //tour guide description in text view
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.guide_desc);



        Intent i= getIntent();

        //getting attached intent data
        String item = i.getStringExtra("selected item");

        //displaying selected item name
        textView.setText(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to insert image to a listview item from sqlite database and pass it into next activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469525/android-how-to-insert-image-to-a-listview-item-from-sqlite-database-and-pass-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can pass the image path using `intent.putExtra("ipath",imagePath)` before calling the `startActivity(intent)`. And then get this path in your next activity. Load the image now..

Answer (score 0):

retrieve image path from db and stored in hashset or hashmap and then stored in sharedprefrence and in next activity you can get the image from sharepreference. Hope you get all those things