# How to pass a image dynamically from one activity to another activity and display it in imageview through JSON

Tags: android, json, android-imageview

I am passing values from one activity to another activity through JSON. I am able to receive string values in the next activity. But I have no idea on sending the mage. Meanwhile all are dynamic values from array.

Sending like the following:

```
jsonobj.put(“Location”, “Chennai”);

jsonobj.put(“Name”, “test1”);

Receving like the following:

location = MainActivity.jsonobj.getString(“Location”);

name =MainActivity.jsonobj.getString(“Name”);
```

Please help me on how to send image dynamically and display it in the next activity.

Comment: just pass the name of the image as a string

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of passing data between 2 activities is as below.

**FromActivity.java**

```
Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ImageDetails", imgDetails);
startActivity(i);
/* Note: imgDetails can be an object with image details of ImageDetails.java class (or) 
you can set as many properties separately using putExtra multiple times. 
If you are using a class, make it serializable.
*/
```

**ToActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.imgDetails = (ImageDetails) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ImageDetails");
    ...
}
```

Thanks
Sriram

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the path of the image in intent as string and set it in imageview.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("image_url", imageUrl);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: this is not the answer and should be in comment

Comment: I hope this will answer his question :-)

Comment: @Sankar ganesh can you explain what is the path with an example

Comment: If it is local image  -                                                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("image_url", "/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
startActivity(intent)

Comment: If it is an image from web it could be the Url of image @Charuka

Answer (score 0):

In your first Activity

Convert ImageView to Bitmap

```
 imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

In second Activity

```
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Then set the bitmap to imageview.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

In your first Activity

Convert ImageView to Bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

In second Activity

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Then display bitmap in ImageView.

**Method 2:**

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it as a String and take it from the next activity.You said you can do that so i am not explaining that part!If you have a url anyway it's a string so no need to worry at all. Assuming you send the image name without its file type that's the light weight way.

If you want to get the **ID** of the image which is in the drawable folder use the String you got

```
int id1 = getResources().getIdentifier(StringImageNameWithOutPng, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

If you want the **drawable**

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourCurrantActivity.this, id1);
```

Now use it as you want

```
whateverImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

More : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519855/5188159