# how i send image from image view to next activity here this is the code where image shownn in image view

Tags: java, android, performance

//this is code where i get the image from previous activity

```
i = getIntent();
getimage = i.getStringExtra("uri");

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

options.inSampleSize = 6;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage, options);

Log.e("arun", "arun" + bitmap);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

//now how i send it to next activity to show this in imageview of next activity
//in next activity i have write

```
bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

//but error occur

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity

Comment: you can pass url from activity 1 to activity 2 and load it again in your imageview.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for sending and Receiving Bitmap

For **Sending Bitmap :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImg", bitmap);
```

For **Receiveing Bitmap use getParcelableExtra() Method**

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);
```

Second activity

```
 Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
yourimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

First.Java

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

Bundle bd = new Bundle();
bd.putParcelable("imagemap", image);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second.Java

```
Bundle bd = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bitmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagemap");
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make one singleton class for the image passing here, may share code can you please show it.

```
public class DataTransaction {

    private static volatile DataTransaction instance = null;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private DataTransaction() {
    }

    public static DataTransaction getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DataTransaction.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DataTransaction();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Bitmap getBimap() {
        return mapView;
    }

    public void setBimap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
DataTransaction model = DataTransaction.getInstance();
model.setBitmap(...);

Bitmap bitmap = DataTransaction.getInstance().getBimap();
```

Comment: //i have use this code to get image from image view    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
        startActivity(intent);    //and i have use code in next activity  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImg");  but ihave get an error of null pointer in getparceble extera

Comment: you just replace intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap) this line with DataTransaction model = DataTransaction.getInstance();
model.setBitmap(...); and when open your second activity then Bitmap bitmap = DataTransaction.getInstance().getBimap();

Comment: This solution is efficient because of no need to cast each and every time your Parcelable data to bitmap.