# Android ClassCastException Error - String cannot be cast to ArrayList

Tags: android, android-intent

```
ImageActivity:
fullImage = (ArrayList<mehndiimg>) bundle.getSerializable("images");
MainActivity:
bundle.putSerializable("images",img.getImages());
```

**ERROR**

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a string to ArrayList, which is impossible.

```
fullImage = (ArrayList) bundle.getSerializable("images");

bundle.getSerializable("images") //this returns a string
```

I supose you're trying to pass images through activities, [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity).