# pass imagview resource to intent

Tags: android

How can I pass an ImageView resource from one activity to another activity?
Have tried `imagview.resource` and `imageview.drawable` to pass this data through intent. But neither works.

![enter image description here][1]

Below, I want to send image 1 to add in recyclerview of image 2.

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Do you use `db` to load data in RecyclerView? add your model and adapter code to investigate

Comment: Passing the whole image resource is a bad idea. How are you getting the images? Are you getting it from a server or loading from app resources?

Answer (score 0):

unreachable, but you can get the value you want by making `imageview.setTag (key, tag)` and then pulling it with the `imageview.getTag()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Convert drawable to Bitmap and then into byte array form and then you can pass it via intent to another activity

See Below link :
[Passing image from one activity another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: This is not an optimal approach. Intent has a limit of 1MB data. If the bitmap data is more than 1MB, it would crash the app.