# Set ImageView to another activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile

I know this is common to ask, but I'm confused about how can I pass the data bitmap Image back to the first activity,when I click the button from first Activity it will goes to the second activity, when the user done filling the signatories it will have the format of `bitmap` and pressing save will display the image bitmap back to the first Activity, how can I achieve this?, I tried the following code below but it doesn't display the image, need help

[image][image]

Currently I'm trying this code below to pass from `second activity to first activity` but it doesn't work

```
Bitmap bitmap = signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageExample", bitmap.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

**First Activity**

```
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    image = findViewById(R.id.imgUri);

    //get image from second activity
    getImage();

    btnNext.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

    public void getImage(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String resultUri = extras.getString("imageExample");
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);
            image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 374, 500, false));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accomplished_signature);

    SignaturePad signaturePad = findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);
    Button buttonSignature = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    Button buttonClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    buttonClear.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signaturePad.clear();
        }
    });

    buttonSignature.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageExample", bitmap.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            signaturePad.clear();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: use `byteArray` to get back image from another to the first activity. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519855/16765223

Answer (score 0):

you'r trying to convert a bitmap to a string which is not possible, instead do it like this :

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class); intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);`

in order to retreive it from your sencod activity :

`Intent intent = getIntent(); Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");`